# cannot rename files with gui

Tags: gui

When I right click -> rename, then name is highlighted, and I can highlight the characters in the file name, but the machine ignores any keys I press, and the name doesn't change. I have to use the terminal to do mv in order to rename anything, and that gets annoying...

Does anyone know if this is a confirmed bug, or weird settings?

EDIT: also when I try and search for files with the default file browser by clicking on the magnifying class, the cursor disappears, and all the keys I press to input search terms are ignored.

EDIT2 Problem fixed... apparently all I had to do was log out and lock back in and the problem was fixed...